# Failed to Load XML documentation

Tags: unity-game-engine

SO while I was test running my application in unity, I got an error where it says "Failed to Load XML documentation: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted" I am a beginner at programming and I don't have any idea how to fix this. What does this error mean and how do i fix this?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snGS7.png)

Comment: can you tell us what are you trying to execute , the code you're using or at least what do you want to achieve here ! throwing the error like this won't give us any idea what actually went wrong here !

Comment: Sorry late reply... Somehow restarting visual studio and unity made the error go away... somehow that fixed it. I don't really know what's going on their previously honestly.